# How can I calculate a time span in Java and format the output?

Tags: java, date, time, formatting

I want to take two times (in seconds since epoch) and show the difference between the two in formats like:

- 2 minutes
- 1 hour, 15 minutes
- 3 hours, 9 minutes
- 1 minute ago
- 1 hour, 2 minutes ago

How can I accomplish this??

Comment: Since it's utterly impossible to ask a question about Java dates on this site without somebody suggesting it, let me just say "Joda Date".

Comment: I don't know if it will do what you want, but that never seems to stop the Joda zealots.

Comment: Ha! That's funny coming a minute before a "JODA" answer.

Comment: No, wait, make that two. (I've never used Joda Time, so don't take this as criticism. It might very well be the best answer.)

Comment: I wouldn't add an entirely new library for this 1 little bit of functionality.

Comment: I never understood why sun/etc didn't implement a datespan or timespan class directly.  given a Date or Timestamp class this is the first use case, isn't it?

Comment: In reference to JODA: looks useful, but it's like 500k... I mean, REALLY?!?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Likewise, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), and advises migration to java.time.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

<sup>*Since everyone shouts "YOODAA!!!" but noone posts a concrete example, here's my contribution.*</sup>

You could also do this with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Use [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) to represent a period. To format the period in the desired human representation, use [`PeriodFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html) which you can build by [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html).

Here's a kickoff example:

```
DateTime myBirthDate = new DateTime(1978, 3, 26, 12, 35, 0, 0);
DateTime now = new DateTime();
Period period = new Period(myBirthDate, now);

PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendYears().appendSuffix(" year, ", " years, ")
    .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" month, ", " months, ")
    .appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" week, ", " weeks, ")
    .appendDays().appendSuffix(" day, ", " days, ")
    .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hour, ", " hours, ")
    .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minute, ", " minutes, ")
    .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" second", " seconds")
    .printZeroNever()
    .toFormatter();

String elapsed = formatter.print(period);
System.out.println(elapsed + " ago");
```

Much more clear and concise, isn't it?

This prints by now

```
32 years, 1 month, 1 week, 5 days, 6 hours, 56 minutes, 24 seconds ago
```

<sup><sub>(Cough, old, cough)</sub></sup>

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). The java.time classes include `Period` & `Duration` classes. The *ThreeTen-Extra* project offers `Interval`.

Answer (score 45):

```
    Date start = new Date(1167627600000L); // JANUARY_1_2007
    Date end = new Date(1175400000000L); // APRIL_1_2007


    long diffInSeconds = (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000;

    long diff[] = new long[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    /* sec */diff[3] = (diffInSeconds >= 60 ? diffInSeconds % 60 : diffInSeconds);
    /* min */diff[2] = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 60)) >= 60 ? diffInSeconds % 60 : diffInSeconds;
    /* hours */diff[1] = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 60)) >= 24 ? diffInSeconds % 24 : diffInSeconds;
    /* days */diff[0] = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 24));

    System.out.println(String.format(
        "%d day%s, %d hour%s, %d minute%s, %d second%s ago",
        diff[0],
        diff[0] > 1 ? "s" : "",
        diff[1],
        diff[1] > 1 ? "s" : "",
        diff[2],
        diff[2] > 1 ? "s" : "",
        diff[3],
        diff[3] > 1 ? "s" : ""));
```

Comment: Is there any reason diff[0] is not called days, diff[1] called minutes etc.

Comment: This solution only works in English, and will be a real pain to internationalise. (Another minor point: it will print "0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 1 second ago" for an interval of 1 second; wouldn't you want to skip the first 3 bits?")

Comment: This solution will give wrong results at least two days in a year, when the daylight saving time is switched on and off. Moreover, you will need to truncate all your dates to midnight for it to work properly all the other days.

Answer (score 17):

Yup awakened the dead I have, but here's my improved implementation based on @mtim posted code, as this thread comes almost on top of the searches so I am messing with the sleepy hollow,

```
    public static String getFriendlyTime(Date dateTime) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Date current = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    long diffInSeconds = (current.getTime() - dateTime.getTime()) / 1000;

    /*long diff[] = new long[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
    /* sec *  diff[3] = (diffInSeconds >= 60 ? diffInSeconds % 60 : diffInSeconds);
    /* min *  diff[2] = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 60)) >= 60 ? diffInSeconds % 60 : diffInSeconds;
    /* hours *  diff[1] = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 60)) >= 24 ? diffInSeconds % 24 : diffInSeconds;
    /* days * diff[0] = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 24));
     */
    long sec = (diffInSeconds >= 60 ? diffInSeconds % 60 : diffInSeconds);
    long min = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 60)) >= 60 ? diffInSeconds % 60 : diffInSeconds;
    long hrs = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 60)) >= 24 ? diffInSeconds % 24 : diffInSeconds;
    long days = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 24)) >= 30 ? diffInSeconds % 30 : diffInSeconds;
    long months = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 30)) >= 12 ? diffInSeconds % 12 : diffInSeconds;
    long years = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 12));

    if (years > 0) {
        if (years == 1) {
            sb.append("a year");
        } else {
            sb.append(years + " years");
        }
        if (years <= 6 && months > 0) {
            if (months == 1) {
                sb.append(" and a month");
            } else {
                sb.append(" and " + months + " months");
            }
        }
    } else if (months > 0) {
        if (months == 1) {
            sb.append("a month");
        } else {
            sb.append(months + " months");
        }
        if (months <= 6 && days > 0) {
            if (days == 1) {
                sb.append(" and a day");
            } else {
                sb.append(" and " + days + " days");
            }
        }
    } else if (days > 0) {
        if (days == 1) {
            sb.append("a day");
        } else {
            sb.append(days + " days");
        }
        if (days <= 3 && hrs > 0) {
            if (hrs == 1) {
                sb.append(" and an hour");
            } else {
                sb.append(" and " + hrs + " hours");
            }
        }
    } else if (hrs > 0) {
        if (hrs == 1) {
            sb.append("an hour");
        } else {
            sb.append(hrs + " hours");
        }
        if (min > 1) {
            sb.append(" and " + min + " minutes");
        }
    } else if (min > 0) {
        if (min == 1) {
            sb.append("a minute");
        } else {
            sb.append(min + " minutes");
        }
        if (sec > 1) {
            sb.append(" and " + sec + " seconds");
        }
    } else {
        if (sec <= 1) {
            sb.append("about a second");
        } else {
            sb.append("about " + sec + " seconds");
        }
    }

    sb.append(" ago");


    /*String result = new String(String.format(
    "%d day%s, %d hour%s, %d minute%s, %d second%s ago",
    diff[0],
    diff[0] > 1 ? "s" : "",
    diff[1],
    diff[1] > 1 ? "s" : "",
    diff[2],
    diff[2] > 1 ? "s" : "",
    diff[3],
    diff[3] > 1 ? "s" : ""));*/
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It obviously can be improved. basically it tries to get the time span more friendly, there are a few limitation though i.e. it would behave strangely if the time passed (parameter) is in future, and its limited up to the days, hours and seconds only (months and years not handled, so that someone else can ;-).

sample outputs are:

- about a second ago
- 8 minutes and 34 seconds ago
- an hour and 4 minutes ago
- a day ago
- 29 days ago
- a year and 3 months ago

, cheers :D

EDIT: now supports months and years :P

Answer (score 13):

I'd recommend you have a look at [HumanTime](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/java/date-formatting-parsing-humans-humantime.html)

Comment: HumanTime is buggy:

long time = 82735786;
System.out.println(TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
System.out.println(HumanTime.approximately(time));

Results in:

22 and
1d 23h respectively 

It's actually 22.9821628 hours.

Answer (score 13):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The other Answers may be correct but are outdated. The troublesome old date-time classes in Java are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Likewise, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## Using java.time

### `Instant`

> two times (in seconds since epoch)

In java.time, we represent moments on the timeline in UTC as `Instant`. I will assume that your epoch is the same as that of java.time, the first moment of 1970 in UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`). Note that an `Instant` has a resolution of nanoseconds. A convenience factory method constructs a `Instant` from whole seconds, as asked in the Question.

```
Instant start = Instant.ofEpochSecond( … );
Instant stop = Instant.ofEpochSecond( … );
```

Here we use the current moment and some minutes later.

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;
Instant stop = start.plusSeconds( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds( 7L ) ) ;  // Seven minutes as a number of seconds.
```

### `Duration`

In java.time, a span of time unattached to the timeline is represented in two ways. For years-month-days, we have `Period`. For hours-minutes-seconds, we have `Duration`.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

### Half-Open

The elapsed time is calculated with the Half-Open approach. In this approach, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This approach is commonly used in date-time work. I believe using this approach consistently across your code base will help to eliminate errors and misunderstandings due to ambiguities, and will ease the cognitive load of your programming.

### ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines many practical formats for representing date-time values as text. These formats are designed to avoid ambiguity, be easy to parse by machine, and be intuitive to read by humans across cultures.

The java.time classes use these formats by default when parsing & generating strings.

For a span of time unattached to the timeline, the [standard defines a format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) of `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` marks the beginning and `T` separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds. So an hour and a half is `PT1H30M`.

In our example code using seven minutes:

```
String outputStandard = duration.toString();
```

> PT7M

See the above example [code running live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/fQnoDc).

I suggest sticking with these formats whenever possible, certainly when exchanging or serializing date-time data, but also consider using in a user interface where appropriate and your users can be trained to use them.

I recommend *never* using the clock-hour format (ex: 01:30 for hour-and-a-half) as that format is completely ambiguous with a time-of-day.

### Retrieving parts to build a String

If you must spell out the span of time as seen in the Question, you will need to build up the text yourself.

- For [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html), call [`getYears`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#getYears--), `getMonths`, and `getDays` to retrieve each part.
- Oddly, the `Duration` class lacked such getters in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), but gained them in [Java 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later: [`toDaysPart`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toDaysPart--), `toHoursPart`, `toMinutesPart`, `toSecondsPart`, and `toNanosPart`.

Some example code, simple and basic to get you started.

```
int days = duration.toDaysPart() ;
int hours = duration.toHoursPart() ;
int minutes = duration.toMinutesPart() ;
int seconds = duration.toSecondsPart() ;
int nanos = duration.toNanosPart() ;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( 100 );

if( days != 0 ) { 
    sb.append( days + " days" ) ;
};

if( hours != 0 ) { 
    sb.append( ( sb.length = 0 ) ? ( "" ) : ( ", " ) ) ;  // Append comma if any existing text.
    sb.append( hours + " hours" ) ;
};

if( minutes != 0 ) { 
    sb.append( ( sb.length = 0 ) ? ( "" ) : ( ", " ) ) ;  // Append comma if any existing text.
    sb.append( minutes + " minutes" ) ;
};

if( seconds != 0 ) { 
    sb.append( ( sb.length = 0 ) ? ( "" ) : ( ", " ) ) ;  // Append comma if any existing text.
    sb.append( seconds + " seconds" ) ;
};

if( nanos != 0 ) { 
    sb.append( ( sb.length = 0 ) ? ( "" ) : ( ", " ) ) ;  // Append comma if any existing text.
    sb.append( nanos + " nanos" ) ;
};

String output = sb.toString();
```

Or perhaps you could write slicker code using [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) in a manner shown with Joda-Time in [the Answer by Balus C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2796052/642706).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), andfz [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Good, informative answer for those of us who can target Java 8+. Thanks Basil!

Comment: @PerLundberg Also good for those targeting Java 6, Java 7, and Android. See the bulleted items at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Java, but you can do t1-t2=t3(in seconds) then divide that by 60, would give you minutes, by another 60 would give you seconds. Then it's just a matter of figuring out how many divisions you need.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your time-spans cross daylight-saving (summer-time) boundaries, do you want to report the number of days?

For example, 23:00 to 23:00 the next day is always a day but may be 23, 24 or 25 hours depending on whether the you cross a daylight-savings transition.

If you care about that, make sure you factor it into your choice.

Comment: The differences are measured in time-since-epoch, so there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

some code that plays with date formatting... and time ago.

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss"); 
    try {
        Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(pubDate);

        SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy ss:mm:hh");              
        String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj); 
        Log.v("THE NEW DATE IS",newDateStr);            
        long pubdateinmilis = dateObj.getTime();            
        pubDate = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(pubdateinmilis, System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS,DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenient methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getFormattedDuration(1619575035, 1619810961));
    }

    public static String getFormattedDuration(long start, long end) {
        Instant startInstant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(start);
        Instant endInstant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(end);

        Duration duration = Duration.between(startInstant, endInstant);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        return String.format("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds", duration.toDays(), duration.toHours() % 24,
                duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        // return String.format("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds",
        // duration.toDaysPart(), duration.toHoursPart(),
        // duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2 days, 17 hours, 32 minutes, 6 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I always start with [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html). Working with dates and times in Java is always "fun" but Joda Time takes the strain off.

They have Interval and Duration classes which do half of what you are looking for. Not sure if they have a function for outputing in readable format though. I'll keep looking.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class can handle most date related math. You will have to get the result of [compareTo](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo(java.util.Calendar)) and output the format yourself though. There isn't a standard library that does exactly what you're looking for, though there might be a 3rd party library that does.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a brief peruse of the API it seems that you could do the following: -

1. create some ReadableInstants representing start time and end time.
2. Use Hours.hoursBetween to get the number of hours
3. use Minutes.minutesBetween to get the number of minutes
4. use mod 60 on the minutes to get the remaining minutes
5. et voila!

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The solution of "Abduliam Rehmanius" seems pretty nice, or you can use some above library or you can create new simple things, refer the JS solution at here: http://www.datejs.com/. It's not difficult to transform into Java lang :-)

Hope my link useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

Formatting time spans in java pops up for me frequently in ETL or DB pulls. The following code snippet is how I get the pulse of the operation.

```
    SimpleDateFormat ymdhms=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###"); /* ("#,###.00"); gives you the decimal fractions */
    int counter=0;
    Date beginTime0=new Date();
    while (<some end condition>) {

        <some time consuming operation>

        /*// uncomment this section durring initial exploration of the time consumer
        if(counter>100000){
            System.out.println("debug exiting due to counter="+counter);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        */

        if(0==counter%1000){
            Date now = new Date();
            long diffInSeconds = (now.getTime() - beginTime0.getTime()) / 1000;
            long diff[] = new long[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            diff[3] = (diffInSeconds >= 60 ? diffInSeconds % 60 : diffInSeconds);                        /* sec   */ 
            diff[2] = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 60)) >= 60 ? diffInSeconds % 60 : diffInSeconds; /* min   */ 
            diff[1] = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 60)) >= 24 ? diffInSeconds % 24 : diffInSeconds; /* hours */ 
            diff[0] = (diffInSeconds = (diffInSeconds / 24));                                            /* days  */ 
            String delta = String.format(
                "%s%s%s%s"
                ,(diff[0]>0?String.format("%d day%s "    ,diff[0],(diff[0]!=1?"s":"")):"")
                ,(diff[1]>0?String.format("%2d hour%s "  ,diff[1],(diff[1]!=1?"s":" ")):"")
                ,(diff[2]>0?String.format("%2d minute%s ",diff[2],(diff[2]!=1?"s":" ")):"")
                ,           String.format("%2d second%s ",diff[3],(diff[3]!=1?"s":" "))
            );
            System.out.println(String.format(
                "%12s %s delta= %s"
                ,formatter.format(counter)
                ,ymdhms.format(new Date())
                ,delta
                )
            );
        }
        counter++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like **PrettyTime**
PrettyTime is an OpenSource time formatting library. Completely customizable, it creates *human readable*, *relative timestamps* like those seen on Digg, Twitter, and Facebook.Its available in over 30 languages!
link:
https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime

Can be used in android too

For example

```
System.out.println(p.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000*60*10)));
        //prints: "10 minutes from now"
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got the same requirement where I need a basic method to print duration. I was not having an option to use any third party library. So I just refined the idea of @mtim further.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        String since = "2017-02-24T04:44:05.601Z";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(utc);

        Date sinceDate = dateFormat.parse(since);
        Date now = new Date();
        long durationInSeconds  = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - sinceDate.getTime());

        long SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE = 60;
        long MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR = 60;
        long HOURS_IN_A_DAY = 24;
        long DAYS_IN_A_MONTH = 30;
        long MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR = 12;

        long sec = (durationInSeconds >= SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE) ? durationInSeconds % SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE : durationInSeconds;
        long min = (durationInSeconds /= SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE) >= MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR ? durationInSeconds%MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR : durationInSeconds;
        long hrs = (durationInSeconds /= MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR) >= HOURS_IN_A_DAY ? durationInSeconds % HOURS_IN_A_DAY : durationInSeconds;
        long days = (durationInSeconds /= HOURS_IN_A_DAY) >= DAYS_IN_A_MONTH ? durationInSeconds % DAYS_IN_A_MONTH : durationInSeconds;
        long months = (durationInSeconds /=DAYS_IN_A_MONTH) >= MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR ? durationInSeconds % MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR : durationInSeconds;
        long years = (durationInSeconds /= MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR);

        String duration = getDuration(sec,min,hrs,days,months,years);
        System.out.println(duration);
    }
    private static String getDuration(long secs, long mins, long hrs, long days, long months, long years) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String EMPTY_STRING = "";
        sb.append(years > 0 ? years + (years > 1 ? " years " : " year "): EMPTY_STRING);
        sb.append(months > 0 ? months + (months > 1 ? " months " : " month "): EMPTY_STRING);
        sb.append(days > 0 ? days + (days > 1 ? " days " : " day "): EMPTY_STRING);
        sb.append(hrs > 0 ? hrs + (hrs > 1 ? " hours " : " hour "): EMPTY_STRING);
        sb.append(mins > 0 ? mins + (mins > 1 ? " mins " : " min "): EMPTY_STRING);
        sb.append(secs > 0 ? secs + (secs > 1 ? " secs " : " secs "): EMPTY_STRING);
        sb.append("ago");
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

The output will be time gap (duration) printed in words e.g.
`1 day 2 hours 51 mins 41 secs ago`

Answer (score 0):

This question is old and already has an answer but i have a better solution.
Use relativeSpan from date utils

```
                dateHere.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timeInMillis,
                        System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS));
```

it takes arguments: long/int time, current time and how you want it, _month,minute,second etc

Answer (score -2):

```
long time1, time2;
time1 = System.currentMillis();

.. drink coffee

time2 = System.currentMillis();

long difference = time2 - time1 // millies between time1 and time2

java.util.Date differneceDate = new Date(difference);
```

To create a string like "2 Minutes" you should use DateFormatter/DateFormat. You can find more details on this in the the Java API spec (java.sun.com).

Comment: A difference in two dates doesn't make a valid date - if your two times are 12 hours apart, "12 noon, 1 January 1970" is not the duration.

Comment: The difference I used is a long. The Date may be used to convert the diffence (long) into a human readable string.

Comment: No, this is wrong.  Imagine time1 and time2 are only 1ms apart.  Calling new Date(1L); will give you a date that's 1ms past midnight Jan 1, 1970 GMT, which is obviously meaningless.