# How to read files of a directory by the order of modified time

Tags: java, file, timestamp

I have one question for read files of a directory. First,

`String[] files = sourceDirectory.list();`

I collect some data traces and put them in a directory. I wish to read the files in the order of created  time because I want to keep the sequence of data traces.

In the `File.list()` documentation, it can not guarantee a consistency order. How can I read files in an order?

The second question is: I want to compute the interval time between 2 messages from message name because message names have time stamp information. For example,

`trace2011_Aug_3__0_0_1` and `trace2011_Aug_3__0_0_5`. How can I convert the string values into Date object and compute the difference between them?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Get the `File`s using `listFiles()` and then sort them by the last modified time using `File.lastModified()`.

```
File[] files = sourceDirectory.listFiles();

Arrays.sort( files, new Comparator<File>() {
    public int compare( File a, File b ) {
        return a.lastModified() - b.lastModified();
    }
});
```

To convert a file name with a date in it, extract the date portion using `String.substring()` and then convert that resulting substring into a date. After that, getting the difference should be easy.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Nice catch, I guess I missed that when I glossed over the API.

Answer (score 2):

For the first half of your question:

```
File[] files = sourceDir.listFiles();

Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() { 
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
    }
});

// Now files should be sorted by timestamp.
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question: just use `File.listFiles()` and sort the resultaing array of `File` instances using `Arrays.sort` and a custom comparator comparing the `lastModified` value of the files. Then iterate through the sorted array.

Regarding the second question: Use `String.substring` to extract the date part from the message, and use `SimpleDateFormat` with the appropriate pattern to change each string into a `Date` object. The interval is just the difference between the time in milliseconds (obtained via `Date.getTime()`) of the two dates.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is to shell out and read the output.  This link has a pretty ugly method for getting the creation date from the file:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/51670

As far as the date parsing is concerned, you can create a custom date formatter and use it to parse your date values:

http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/ParseDate.html

Once you have the date parsing working, use this method to get the difference:

[How can I calculate a time span in Java and format the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635935/how-can-i-calculate-a-time-span-in-java-and-format-the-output)

Good luck!

Comment: Just a side note:  I was assuming you needed date created, not date modified - if you're looking for the modified date, the other methods in this post are a better bet.

Answer (score 0):

First question: see tskuzzy´s answer.

Second question: Write a parser-class/method and use the substring method to convert the strings to date. (in fact only you know, how the string is built). Maybe [Apache´s String Utils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) help you with it.