# Difference between two times in android

Tags: android, date-difference

I want to get difference between two times. I calculate this by using following.

[using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635935/how-can-i-calculate-a-time-span-in-java-and-format-the-output)

But i want to calculate three difference. For example i have 6 TIME as following.

time1, time2, time3, time4

And I want to calculate difference between two times like

`long difference1=time2-time1;`
`long difference2=time4-time3;`
`long difference3=time6-time5;`

Then i want addition of these three differences. like difference1+difference2+difference3.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: What do you want the difference units to be?  It's easy to do in milliseconds, however, the sum of the differences won't translate into anything meaningful.

Comment: I want difference between two Times and add all diffrences.

Comment: But that's not a problem! What you wrote on your question is no question, it's the "problem" (let's call it that way) solved! You already got all differences. 1 2 and 3.... what do you want to do with them now? I down voted your question until you better explain yourself.

Comment: Have 6 time values. time1,time2,..time6. Now i get difference between these like (time2-time1),(time4-time3),(time6-time5). And after difference i want to add all these three differences.

Comment: Long ---->totalDiff<----- = dif1 + dif2 + dif3!!! What more do you want?

Comment: Yes exactly what i need. But i need totalDIff in hours:min:sec format.

Comment: Can i know why you give me down votes? This is my requirement so that i ask it. sorry for any mistack.

Comment: hardik jushi, I down voted your question beacuse even after asking you exactly what you wanted you didn't answer or updated your question until your comment. Why didn't you post this on the question? "But i need totalDIff in hours:min:sec format" You never told people what you really wanted!!! Even now, anybody coming here won't understant it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long difference1 = date2.getTime()-date1.getTime();  
long difference2 = date4.getTime()-date3.getTime();  
long difference3 = date6.getTime()-date5.getTime();

ling totalDifference = difference1 + difference2 + difference3;
```

this totalDifference is in milliseconds and you can convert it in Day:Hour:Min:Seconds by

```
days = (int) (totalDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));  
hours = (int) ((totalDifference - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));  
min = (int) (totalDifference - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days) - (1000 * 60 * 60 * hours))/ (1000 * 60);
```

Comment: This is not done. I don't get sum value of total differences.

Comment: you must get sum of difference1, difference2 and difference3 in totalDifference

Comment: I get totaldifference. But not get days,hours,min. when i print days:hours:min it display 0:00 value.

Comment: How we calculate seconds like hours and min which you calculate?

Comment: sec = (int) (totalDifference - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days) - (1000 * 60 * 60 * hours)-(1000 * 60 * min))/ (1000);

Comment: Yes @Nirav i accept it and now you are comming into chat room. Thank you so so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
long totalTime = (date2.getTime()-date1.getTime() + date4.getTime()-date3.getTime() + date6.getTime()-date5.getTime());

Date totalDifDate = new Date(totalTimeMillis);
```

Comment: I don't get perfect idea what you say.

Answer (score 0):

Better use Calendar class and GregorianClaendar instead of Date class.

```
Date time1, time2, time3, time4;
[...]
GregorianCalendar difference12 = new GregorianCalendar(0,0,0,0,0);
difference12.set(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECNOD, time1.getTime() - time2.getTime());

GregorianCalendar difference34 = new GregorianCalendar(0,0,0,0,0);
difference12.add(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECNOD, time3.getTime() - time4.getTime());

Date diff12 = difference12.getGregorianChange();
Date diff34 = difference34.getGregorianChange();
GregorianCalendar sum = new GregorianCalendar(0,0,0,0,0);
sum.add(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND, diff12.getTime() - time34.getTime());
```