# How to subtract two time by converting them to get long

Tags: java, time, long-integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I calculate a time span in Java and format the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635935/how-can-i-calculate-a-time-span-in-java-and-format-the-output)

How to subtract two time by converting them to get long and convert it back to time again?

I tried subtracting two time by converting them to long.

```
    Long timeSpan = Long.valueOf(timespan.getValue().toString()) * 60;
    Long checkVar = (date.getTime() - testStartTime.getTime()) / 1000;
```

Now how do i convert the resultant long into time?

That is if the result long is say 30 min i want it to be shown 00:30:00 .

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using an library like [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for this?

Comment: @BjörnPollex this isn't a duplicate of that question - the required output format is completely different.

Comment: @Alnitak: Correct, I was overeager there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's trivial to convert your time in seconds into the individual HH:MM:SS components:

```
int h = checkVar / 3600;
int m = (checkVar / 60) % 60;
int s = (checkVar % 60);

String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s);
```

Answer (score 2):

As has already been suggested, take a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

```
PeriodFormatter timeFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().printZeroAlways().
                appendHours().appendSeparator(":").
                appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":").
                appendSeconds().toFormatter();

DateTime startTime = new DateTime(1972, 3, 8, 15, 30);
DateTime endTime = new DateTime();

Period period = new Period(startTime, endTime);
int days = period.getDays();
int months = period.getMonths();
int years = period.getYears();

System.out.println(period.toString(timeFormatter));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date elapsed = new Date(checkVar);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String formatedTime = sdf.format(elapsed);
```

Comment: are you _sure_ this can't get confused by timezones?  Actually this doesn't even appear to be a legal call to `SimpleDateFormat.format` according to the J2SE 7.0 documentation.

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't appear to a legal call?

Comment: +1 You can set the timezone to be GMT.

Comment: @AlexB because the prototype for that function is `StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos)`.

Comment: @Alnitak It's a method inherited from [DateFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date))

Comment: @AlexB my mistake - I didn't spot that in the list of inherited methods.

Comment: This is really not a good idea. Class `java.util.Date` is only suited for storing instants in time, not for storing an amount of time such as "30 minutes". Misusing class `Date` like this can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @Jesper yeah, that's kind of what I was alluding too when I mentioned the potential issue with timezones.