# android format time range as string

Tags: android, datetime-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I calculate a time span in Java and format the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635935/how-can-i-calculate-a-time-span-in-java-and-format-the-output)

Is there a simple function to format time range as a string? 
At the moment I can generate an output like that:

*"81 days"*

```
final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
int today_day = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

final Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
startCal.add(Calendar.Day_OF_YEAR,81);  
int start_day = startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

 int dif= start_day-today_day;
 if (dif >1){
   str = "in "+dif+" days";
 }
```

but I would prefere it to be

*" 2 month and 20 days"*

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use Date Object:

```
Date startDay = new Date(); //today
Date targetDay = new Date();
targetDay.setDate(startDay.getDate() + 81);
Date difference = new Date(startDay.getTime() - targetDay.getTime());
// you may format as you want i.e difference.getMonth()
String differenceDateString = difference.toString();
```

`Calendar`'s `getTime` method returns `Date` object too.