# Calculate Date Ranges Diffrence in C#or Java

Tags: c#, java, date, datetime

I have date Ranges for A and B like below
d1,d2...d3 are actual Date
I need to get date Ranges that are Covered by A but not by B in Output. I am thinking of creating a function that collects date range arrays for A and B and then take A and compare against each ranges for B and evaluate the diff. my question is that, is there a better way to do this and is there a function that returns Date range Difference given pair of date Ranges.

```
|d1-------------d6|    |d9----------d14|    |d16----------------d21|  **Line For A
    |d5--------------d10|   |d12----d14|       |d17-----------d20|   |d25-------d30| **Line For B

Output:
d1  d5
d10 d12
d16 d17
d20 d21
```

Comment: d1 is actually integer representation of dates so 1/21/2012 will be d1=20120121. so DateRange will have pair of dates

Comment: You will have to precisely define what you mean. If you do so, you might find that you've pretty much written the algorithm. ;)

Comment: For example, I don't understand why d6..d9 doesn't count as a difference.

Comment: because d6 to d9 is covered by B already. what i need is ranges not covered by B but covered by A

Comment: -1 I googled https://www.google.com/search?q=Calculate+Date+Ranges+Diffrence+in+C%23 and found the answer in the first link. Next time try researching the topic.

Comment: i am not trying to find diffrence in dates in days, that's too easy

Comment: Ok I get you now. There's definitely no ready written function to do that, I'm afraid.

Comment: but is my approach a better solution...or is there more known pattern to solve this type of date ranges problem

Comment: @JustinHomes when did I say Days? you use a `TimeSpan` to get whatever you want.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson the output is not a single date value. its date ranges

Comment: This is not a duplicate of what is being said. need to read the problem not just the title

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime in c#. I don't know if there is a equivalence in Java

Answer (score 0):

I think [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) is what you want:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

TimeSpan t = d1 - d2;
int mins = t.TotalMinutes;  //what ever you want, Years, Months, Days, Hrs, Mins, Seconds
```

In Java the equivilent is [How can I calculate a time span in Java and format the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635935/how-can-i-calculate-a-time-span-in-java-and-format-the-output)

Comment: no because if i have
drangeA=1/1/2012 to 7/5/2012
drangeB=3/1/2012 to 3/15/2012

output should be Dates range Not cover B but by A

1/1/2012 to 3/1/2012 and 
3/15/2012 to 7/5/2012