# Convert java date to sincenow format

Tags: java

I'm having a Java Date and I want to convert this to something like

0s ago or 38m ago.

I've searched for a build in function but I didn't find anything.

What's the best way to convert this?

Comment: A Java `Date` object is just an arbitrary point in time.  What is the _other_ point in time against which you want to compute a difference?

Comment: so it can be `1 year 2 months 5 days 6 hours 36 min 12 sec ago`?

Comment: Can you use Java 8? If so, you will want to look into `Duration` class and friends.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting a Question. This topic has been addressed many times already.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't found a topic. Because I don't know how such a format is called.

Comment: @BasilBourque Maybe there are duplicates for this question, but I don't think the question you have pointed (from 2010) has valid non out-of-date answers for this one.

Comment: @Tristan What would an up-to-date Answer address that is not covered by the Answers on that original Question? And, why not add an up-to-date Answer to that original Question rather than here? I do not know how Stack Overflow policy works in this regard. Please point me to rules or a Meta page if you can.

Comment: Another duplicate: [How can I calculate a time span in Java and format the output?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/635935/642706). @Tristan See [my up-to-date Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42462296/642706) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, dont use the ambiguous "Date" in java, use the new classes introduced in Java 8.

Now, if u have 2 LocalDateTime, (the date of the past event and "now"), you can evaluate the difference between and format it : [Java 8: Calculate difference between two LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-calculate-difference-between-two-localdatetime)

UPDATE : I have to say it's available for java 7 (and 6) only through the backport library : http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/, standard only in java 8